# R: Shiny - How can I rearrange the dateRangeInput() widget?

Tags: r, shiny

Is there a way to display the two input fields of the `dateRangeInput()` widget in such a way that instead of being arranged side-by-side, they are arranged vertically like a stack i.e. `start = <date>` on top of `end = <date>`?

I've looked through the `shiny` documentation and couldn't find a way to get this done and I'm not that good at CSS/Javascript (yet).

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**:
To clarify, here's a snippet from my app:

```
    app <- shinyApp(
               ui = fluidPage(
               sidebarLayout(
                   sidebarPanel(

                       width = 3,

                 # --- code based on selectInput() with choices linking to conditional panels ---

                         tags$div(title = "Request data for a given time period",
                             conditionalPanel(
                                 condition = "input.outputstyle == 'Density plot (week)'",
                                 dateRangeInput("daterange",
                                                label = "Date Range: ",
                                                start = Sys.Date() - 8,
                                                end = Sys.Date() - 1,
                                                max = Sys.Date(),
                                                format = "d M",
                                                separator = "--"))),

                  # --- more code for other conditional panels, etc. ---

                server = function(input, output) {
                          # rest of code
                         }          
       )
```

Answer (score 2):

```
fluidRow(column(width = 12,dateInput("daterange1", "Date range:", start = "2001-01-01")), 
column(width = 12,dateInput("daterange2", "Date range:", end = "2017-01-01")))
```

You can do this with Shiny's dateInput() widget.

Changing the width to 12 does the trick of stacking it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking to do this with `dateRangeInput()` _specifically_.  I have my reasons for using this particular function.

Comment: You could do that by replacing the dateInput to dateRangeInput and adding a end date variable. `fluidRow(column(width = 12,dateRangeInput("daterange1", "Date range:", start = "2001-01-01", end = "2017-01-01")), 
column(width = 12,dateRangeInput("daterange2", "Date range:", start = "2001-01-01", end = "2017-01-01")))`